# Handling map click with svelte-leaflet and get coordinates

Tags: javascript, leaflet, event-handling, svelte

I am trying to find coordinates on map when user click on it, but not when he double click to zoom in. The goal being to create a marker at this point and remember it for later.

As I am using svelte, I believe i should use a premade svelte module, I found [svelte-leaflet](https://ngyewch.github.io/svelte-leaflet/getting-started) that should be able to do the job.

I downloaded their [sample project](https://github.com/ngyewch/svelte-leaflet-test) and start editing from there.

So I just want to get an event so far, so I create a function in `App.svelte`

```js
const on_map_click = (e) => {
        console.log('click')
        console.log(e)
    }
```

And add the event handler:

```html
<div class="example" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <LeafletMap bind:this={leafletMap} options={mapOptions} on:click={on_map_click}>
        <TileLayer url={tileUrl} options={tileLayerOptions} />
    </LeafletMap>
</div>
```

Unfortunately I don't get any event.

So I tried another aproach (not svelte-oriented) :

```js
    onMount(() => {
        leafletMap.getMap().fitBounds([[60.9, -4.8], [45.5, 10.2]]);
        leafletMap.getMap().on('click', on_map_click) // <--- 
    });
```

This approach works, but if I double click it still trigger the event. So I believe there is another way, more adapted to the use case.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a section in the docs https://ngyewch.github.io/svelte-leaflet/event-handling. According to that you have to set `events` on the component for which you want to listen, so

```
 <LeafletMap ... events="{['click']}" on:click={on_map_click}>
```

The event object will be a `CustomEvent` with the original event in the detail

```
  function on_map_click(event) {
        console.log(event.detail.originalEvent)
    }
```

> but if I double click it still trigger the event

I think that's normal behaviour that the click event is also triggered when double clicked. Should a visible marker be set? Maybe this could be done by adding a button which must be pressed while clicking? Or use the `contextmenu` right click?

> As I am using svelte, I believe i should use a premade svelte module

There's no obligation to do so. It might be handy to use a special svelte library, but it is also possible to use the js library directly

This is how you could do it directly with `leaflet` installed [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/dffb9e81222442258aeedd08dabcf2d1?version=3.48.0)

```
<script>
    import L from 'leaflet'
    import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'

    function initMap(node) {
        const map = L.map(node).setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(map);

        L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
            .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
            .openPopup();

        map.on('click', (event) => console.log(event))
    }
</script>

<div use:initMap></div>

<style>
    div {
        height: 600px;
    }
</style>
```